# How can I use Perl to concatenate array elements between two indexes?

Tags: perl

I have an array of strings: `@array`

I want to concatenate all strings beginning with array index `$i` to `$j`.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
$newstring = join('', @array[$i..$j])
```

Comment: thanks. if $j is end of string, i am using scalar(@array)-1 for $j. is there any other way of doing that.

Comment: @iamrohitbanga Yes: `$#array` is a shorter way of saying `scalar@array - 1`

Comment: Sorry I don't follow the "$j is end of string" part. But scalar(@array)-1 is $#array.

Comment: The last time I said that `@array-1 == $#array`, somebody pointed out that "not if `$[` has been changed".  Admittedly, an odd scenario that we usually don't even care to think about, most of the time...

Comment: The point is to use the one that means what you want. Since in this case you want the last thing in `@array`, you write `$#array` because it *means* the last index in `@array`. You don't write `@array - 1` because that means "one less than the number of things in `@array`".

Answer (score 9):

```
my $foo = join '', @array[$i..$j];
```

First we generate an array slice with the values that we want, then we join them on the empty character ''.

Answer (score 2):

Just enclosing a perl array in quotes is enough to concatenate it, if you're happy with spaces as the concatenation character:

```
@array = qw(a b c d e f g);
$concatenated = "@array[2 .. 5]";
print $concatenated;
## prints "c d e f"
```

or of course

```
$" = '-';
@array = qw(a b c d e f g);
$concatenated = "@array[2 .. 5]";
print $concatenated;
```

if you'd prefer "c-d-e-f".

Answer (score -1):

Try this ....

```
use warnings ;
use strict ;
use Data::Dumper ;
my $string ;
map { $string .=  $_; } @arr[$i..$j] ;
print $string ;
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `map` in void context; a `for` loop would work just as well. But loops of any sort are unnecessary when you can just use `join`.

Comment: Is void `map` evil?  I'd use a postfix `for` most places a void `map` can be used.  Here I'd use a `join`.  But Perl 5.8.1 and up optimize away map's return values when called it is called in void context.  For more discussion of map in void context see: http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=296742